# Can I hide only one category from admin post list?

Tags: posts, admin

How can I hide all posts from a single category and not show them in the posts admin screen.

Comment: **How** do you try that? Show us your code please.

Comment: Got it! Answer below!

Answer (score 0):

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
global $pagenow;

if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
return $query;

else {
    $query->set('cat', "-11");
}
return $query;
}
```

Comment: Something is missing. A filter registration maybe? :)